# Cannot share a dish on Facebook in my IOS app

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the error attached. It says, "We couldn't log you in: You can't log in to this app because you do not meet this app's requirements for country, age or other criteria."

Where can I find those requirements. Country is Kuwait by the way

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if your app reference alcohol and you ticked that from Facebook developer console advanced settings it will make this error since many middle east countries restrict alcohol

**check image below**

[Facebook Advanced Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGDyX.png)